# Configure varnish on a different server

Tags: magento, varnish

This is my situation,
I have 2 dedicated servers, one with a Magento installation, and the other without anything.
I would like to use the second server with most of it's RAM with Varnish.

I can't find around an example on how to make Varnish work alone on one server and manage the requests vs the mysite.com on the first server.

Is this possible or Varnish must work on same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's completely possible to have Varnish on seperate server.

You can specify IP address & port in below code where your Magento Web Server resides

```
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content server.

 backend default {
 .host = "127.0.0.1";
 .port = "6081"; 
 }
```